# Ошибка «Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'»?

Tags: gulp, npm, laravel-elixir

Стоит все на Laravel Homestead. Laravel 5.2.

Делаю установку **laravel-elixir** через `npm install`. После выполнения команды `gulp` выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/gulpfile.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

Пробовал удалить папку node_modules и заново запустить `npm install` или `sudo npm install`, проблема не исчезла.

Файл package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил так:

1. Удалил **node_modules** и перезапустил VM
2. Запустил команду `sudo npm install --no-bin-links`
3. После запуска команды `gulp` появилась такая ошибка:

   [13:07:29] Using gulpfile ~/Code/Laravel/gulpfile.js
   [13:07:29] Starting 'default'...
   [13:07:29] Starting 'sass'...
   [13:07:29] 'sass' errored after 58 ms
   [13:07:29] Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-47/binding.node
   This usually happens because your node version has changed.
   Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
       at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:158:11)
       at Object. (/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:16:36)
       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
       at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
       at Object. (/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:186:21)
       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   [13:07:29] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
   Message:
       An error occured in task 'sass'.
   [13:07:29] Finished 'default' after 75 ms
4. Удалил папку node-sass
5. Заново `npm install --no-bin-links`
6. `npm rebuild node-sass --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install 'module-name'
```

В вашем случае:

```
npm install 'laravel-elixir'
```

Answer (score 0):

`latarel-elixir` нужно устанавливать в секцию разработки `-- dev`

```
npm install laravel-elixir --save-dev
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]